# What WYSIWYG editor should I use that will work on mobile?

Tags: mobile, wysiwyg

I'm searching for a WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) editor that will work on mobile, both Android and IOS. It's fine if it won't work on old browsers, but if it will it will be greate. The editor should have bold, under line, color and all the basic stuff like in the basic CKeditor. The returned text should be in HTML / BBcode (both of them will work for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dec 2013 I tried [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/), it worked on all the Androids I tested. With HTML and BBCode.

Check out its github repository: https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor

Hope that helps a tiny bit.